# R : loop to repeat same code on multiples columns

Tags: r, loops

i have a question about a loop in R.
My data contains 2000 rows which are 2000 indiviuals.
I have 37 columns which is 37 continuous variables of diverse information.
I would like to identify outliers with tuckey method for the 37 variables.

Here the code i am using for one column:

```
iqr <- IQR(mydata$x)
q1  <- quantile(mydata$x)[[2]]
q2  <- quantile(mydata$x)[[3]]
q3  <- quantile(mydata$x)[[4]]

mydata$Medium_Outliers_low <- ifelse(mydata$x< q1-1.5*iqr,1,0)
mydata$Medium_Outliers_high <- ifelse(mydata$x> q3+1.5*iqr,1,0)
mydata$Extremes_Outliers_low <- ifelse(mydata$x < q1-3*iqr,1,0)
mydata$Extremes_Outliers_high <- ifelse(mydata$x > q3+3*iqr,1,0)
```

I want to repeat this code for my 37 variables so i will have the 4 variables created (Medium_Outliers_low and co) for each of 37 variables so create a database with 148 variables.

I try a loop :

```
for (i in 4:41){
  iqr <- IQR(mydata[[i]])
  q1  <- quantile(mydata[[i]])[[2]]
  q2  <- quantile(mydata[[i]])[[3]]
  q3  <- quantile(mydata[[i]])[[4]]
  mydata$Medium_Outliers_low <- ifelse(mydata[[i]]< q1-1.5*iqr,1,0)
  mydata$Medium_Outliers_high <- ifelse(mydata[[i]]> q3+1.5*iqr,1,0)
  mydata$Extremes_Outliers_low <- ifelse(mydata[[i]]< q1-3*iqr,1,0)
  mydata$Extremes_Outliers_high <- ifelse(mydata[[i]]> q3+3*iqr,1,0)
```

but i only have created the 4 variables (Medium_Outliers_low and co).
So i would ask for you help for creating a loop to repeating a code because i have no idea to do it. I searched for similar problems but could not find anything.
Many thanks !!!
C.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the Outliers columns were getting overwrited in each iteration and return the output of the last iteration.  It may be better to `paste` with either the index or column name to identify each columns uniquely.

```
for (i in 4:41){
  iqr <- IQR(mydata[[i]])
  qtl <- quantile(mydata[[i]])
  q1  <- qtl[[2]]
  q2  <- qtl[[3]]
  q3  <- qtl[[4]]
  nm1 <- names(mydata)[i]
  mydata[[paste0(nm1, "_Medium_Outliers_low")]] <- 
      ifelse(mydata[[i]]< q1-1.5*iqr,1,0)
  mydata[[paste0(nm1, "_Medium_Outliers_high")]] <- 
     ifelse(mydata[[i]]> q3+1.5*iqr,1,0)
  mydata[[paste0(nm1, "_Extremes_Outliers_low")]] <- 
      ifelse(mydata[[i]]< q1-3*iqr,1,0)
  mydata[[paste0(nm1, "_Extremes_Outliers_high")]] <- 
      ifelse(mydata[[i]]> q3+3*iqr,1,0)
}
```